# C struct or array to design a geometric library

Tags: c, lib

I need to code a lib to manage geometric transforms over points in a 2D space in C. These points will be aggregated in shapes and I want to be able to (auto)vectorize the processing of the full shapes through OpenMP.

The question I'm stuck with is the best way to proceed to declare the points:

```
typedef __attribute__((aligned(8))) float point_t[2];
```

or

```
typedef struct point_t
{
  float x, y;
} point_t;
```

knowing that, later I will use a box type :

```
typedef __attribute__((aligned(64))) point_t box_t[4];
```

From a programming perspective, it is more legible to access `box[1].y` than `box[1][1]` (the y coordinate of the 2nd point of the box rectangle). Now, will the compilers understand that the struct is only a nice handler of an array and vectorize accordingly ?

Comment: Unrelated to what you're actually asking, but... why four points for your box? xywh or ltrb (four floats instead of eight) should be enough for axis-aligned rects, and a fifth "rotation" float should allow rotated rects. Unless the "box" isn't necessarily a rectangle?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Each point has 2 coordinates (x, y), so each N-points polygon needs 2×N floats. No assumption can be made on the geometry of the box, in general.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing. Normally, an axis-aligned rectangle is called a "box". There are definite assumptions here. It is a rectangle (assumption 1) , and it is axis-aligned (assumption 2). Sometimes assumption 2 is dropped, but you need to specifically mention that. OTOH a four-vertice polygon with no assumed properties is normally called a "quadrangle" or simply "quad", rather than "box".

Comment: Where I live, "box" is the name of a generic container, with no assumption made on its shape or number of vertices, let alone alignment. When we narrow down the generality to a particular context, we add adjectives like "rectangular" or "octagonal". So, attributing rigid and definite properties to a noun used without explicit qualifiers is not only dangerous but completely foreign to me. No adjectives = no assumptions = stay safe.

Comment: You live in a weird and wonderful place. On my planet containers are not geometric shapes, but rather data structures that contain other data. We call generic containers, surprise, "containers". And we call generic polygons, surprise, "polygons". In this world, boxes are mostly rectangular. If I order stuff online and I receive an object that has 5 sides or a 120 degree angle, I call it a damaged box and send it back.

Comment: And on your question: `float x, y;` is not what programmers around me prefer. An array is perfectly fine. `float x, y;` is not. I don't want to jump through hoops writing coordinate transformations for `float x, y`, I know how to multiply a matrix by a vector using indices and I already have code to do so, thank you very much. Accessing coordinates as separate entities is not a natural operation to me. I loop over them about 100% of the time, even if it's only a loop from 0 to 1.

Comment: In French I would call an arbitrary 4-sided polygon a "quadrilatère", so I guess "quad" is the most logical equivalent, as a shortening of "quadrilateral"? As for "box", the French equivalent "boîte" only refers to a cardboard box. I never encountered anything but the English "box" when referring to 2D or 3D hit boxes or bounding boxes, which are usually rectangles (or "rectangular parallelepipeds" in 3D :) ) aligned to some referential (e.g. AABB for "axis aligned bounding box").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the compiler. The only way to be sure is to check the result.

The Compiler Explorer at godbolt.org is a convenient way to check what a compiler spits out. I wrote a trivial `translate` function:

```
#ifdef USE_XY
#define X(p) ((p).x)
#define Y(p) ((p).y)
typedef struct point_t
{
  float x, y;
} point_t;
#else
#define X(p) ((p)[0])
#define Y(p) ((p)[1])
typedef __attribute__((aligned(8))) float point_t[2];
#endif

typedef __attribute__((aligned(64))) point_t box_t[4];

void translate(box_t* box, float dx, float dy) {
    #pragma omp simd
    for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
        X((*box)[i]) += dx;
        Y((*box)[i]) += dy;
    }
}
```

Compiling with ARM64 gcc 8.2 (results at https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EEP17Yd7G), we get this for `-O2 -fopenmp` and `-O2 -fopenmp -DUSE_XY`:

```
translate:
        dup     v0.4s, v0.s[0]
        ldr     q3, [x0]
        ldr     q2, [x0, 16]
        ins     v0.s[1], v1.s[0]
        ins     v0.s[3], v1.s[0]
        fadd    v3.4s, v3.4s, v0.4s
        fadd    v0.4s, v2.4s, v0.4s
        str     q3, [x0]
        str     q0, [x0, 16]
        ret
```

...and this for `-O2` and `-O2 -DUSE_XY`:

```
translate:
        add     x1, x0, 32
.L2:
        ldp     s3, s2, [x0]
        fadd    s3, s3, s0
        fadd    s2, s2, s1
        stp     s3, s2, [x0]
        add     x0, x0, 8
        cmp     x0, x1
        bne     .L2
        ret
```

The former uses SIMD instructions, the latter does not. Whether or not `-DUSE_XY` is there doesn't make a difference. So, we know that for this exact code and these exact compiler flags, this exact compiler version is *capable* of doing it. That, of course, does not guarantee that it will succeed for all your code.

Comment: Thank you. I have slightly changed the compilation flags to match my needs closer. Here is the GCC version : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sv9dG6r6j and here is the Clang version : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9r5db6vnG. Notice Clang uses one instruction less.

Answer (score 1):

At any rate, what you will pass to your vector functions is a `float*`. Your only problem is to make sure your `x`,`y` structure maps properly to your 2 elements array.

Even though the C standard doesn't guarantee there will be no padding in a struct (except at the beginning), I can't see a reason for the compiler not to do what you expect.
I'm pretty sure both GNU and Microsoft will pack the two floats in 8 bytes by default.

I'd say a simple `typedef struct { float x,y; } point_t;` should be safe.

You could add a paranoid check just to be on the safe side, for instance:

```
struct { float x,y; } coords; // expected to map to float[2]
float vector[2];
assert (offsetof(coords,x) == 0); // already guaranteed by the C standard
assert (offsetof(coords,y) == sizeof(float));
assert (sizeof(coords) == sizeof(vector));
```

If that code runs fine (or rather the compiler optimizes that code away), I can't see how it could play a dirty trick on you later.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative you might want to consider is using complex numbers, for example

```
typedef _Complex float pointT;
```

Of course you'll want to check out the assembly produced, but it would seem reasonable to hope that the optimiser would do a good job on inbuilt types.

Complex numbers allow some ease in coding.

Addition and subtraction can be written directly without need of writing functions: if a and b are pointT's then
a+b is the pointT that is the sum of a and b.
Similarly scaling a point T by a scalar (integral or floating) can be written directly as multiplication of the point by the scalar.
The length of a point is given by cabs() and its direction by carg().

Rotating and (isotropic) scaling is particularly nice. If p is a point and m a complex number of length s and direction  d, then

```
m = s*cexp( I*d)
m*p is p rotated through d and scaled by s.
```

Moreover if m and n represent such transformations, then

```
m*n represents n then m
```

(and in particular 1/m is the inverse of the transformation represented by m).

If p and q are complex numbers then

```
p*conj(q) is dot(p,q) + I*cross(p,q)
```

Finally an annoying thing that can easily produce bugs is the difference in conventions between mathematical angles, which are anti-clockwise from the x axis, and a common geometrical convention which is to take angles as clockwise from the y axis. If you think of the complex number z as representing y+Ix, so y = creal(z) and x = cimag(z) then the complex number rotations above are the same as the geometrical convention.

A drawback is that if you need to implement other transformations (for example non-isotropic scalings, and shears) then you will need a different representation for them, and it could be awkward not to have one way of representing any (linear) transformation.

Comment: Complex types don't vectorize at all, that's for sure. I ran into this mistake already, that was my first try.